# mergeSort algorithm and memory issue in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-management, v8, mergesort

Here's the code I wrote:

```
function mergeSort(array){
    if(array.length < 2) return array;
    var mid = Math.floor(array.length / 2);
    var left = array.slice(0, mid);
    var right = array.slice(mid, array.length);
    return merge(mergeSort(left), mergeSort(right));
}

function merge(left, right){
    var result = [];
    while (left.length && right.length){
        if(left[0]>right[0]){
            result.push(right[0]);
        } else {
            result.push(left[0]);
        }

    }
    while(left.length){
        result.push(left[0]);
    }
    while(right.length){
        result.push(right[0]);
    }
    return result;
}
array = [1000, -94, -115, 300, 22]
mergeSort(array);
```

and below is another solution i found online

```
    function mergeSort (arr) {
    if (arr.length < 2) return arr;

    var mid = Math.floor(arr.length /2);

    return merge(mergeSort(arr.slice(0,mid)),  mergeSort(arr.slice(mid)));
}

function merge (a,b) {
    var result = [];
    while (a.length >0 && b.length >0)
        result.push(a[0] < b[0]? a.shift() : b.shift());
    return result.concat(a.length? a : b);
}

var test = [-100,3,53,21,4,0];
console.log(mergeSort(test));
```

in comparison I can't find any significant difference besides some syntax. But for some reason mine code won't run in both chrome dev console and node.js environment. In chrome, it won't return any result and in node.js it gives me

`FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory Abort trap: 6`
 Can someone help me understand what is the difference between the two snippet that actually made the difference?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never move from first element when you are doing merge. Try this code:

```
function mergeSort(array){
    if(array.length < 2) return array;
    var mid = Math.floor(array.length / 2);
    var a = array.slice(0, mid);
    var b = array.slice(mid);
    return merge(mergeSort(a), mergeSort(b));
}

function merge(a, b){
    var result = [];
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    while (i < a.length && j < b.length){
        if(a[i] < b[j]){
            result.push(a[i]);
            i++;
        } else {
            result.push(b[j]);
            j++;
        }
    }
    while(i < a.length){
        result.push(a[i]);
        i++;
    }
    while(j < b.length){
        result.push(b[j]);
        j++
    }

    return result;
}

array = [1000, -94, -115, 300, 22];
array = mergeSort(array);
console.log(array);
```

Comment: @SamHe If you can check answer as correct it would be really helpful :)

Comment: @ Luka Lopusina ahh, sorry I'm kinda new. Thanks for the reminder!

Answer (score 2):

Think about it, you have an array `left` and you do

```
while(left.length){
    result.push(left[0]);
}
```

`left[0]` doesn't change the array, it just gets the first item.

The length of `left` will **never** change, what you have there is a while loop that goes on as long as the array has a length over zero, and it always will, as the length never changes.
This is a perfect example of an infinite loop, that eventually fills the callstack and errors out, or in older browsers just crashes.

However if you do

```
while(left.length){
    result.push(left.shift());
}
```

`Array.shift()` **removes** the first item from the array, so at some point the arrays length will be zero, and the loop stops